# Keydown listener doesn't change the property of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, listener, es6-class

I am trying to learn relationship between classes and listeners in javascript. I want to make listener change the properties of an object. I am also trying to use modular code. My class code is:

```
export class Game{
    constructor(){
        this.prop = 1;
        document.onkeydown = this.initListeners;
    }

    initListeners(e){
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            this.prop = 5;
            console.log("Current: " + this.prop);
        }
    }

    play(){
        console.log("Playing: " + this.prop);
        setTimeout(()  => { 
            this.play();
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

During construction, it sets the `prop` property to 1 and it sets the listener so that when the left arrow key is pressed, it sets the `prop` property of object to 5. `play()` method just prints the property recursively.
My app.js (which is included in html) code looks like:

```
import {Game} from "./game.js";

var game = new Game();
game.play();
```

So the desired output is, at first it should print 1 and after pressing the left arrow key, it should start printing 5. But instead, when pressed, it prints `Current: 5` but then continues to print: `Playing: 1`.
What is the problem? and how can I solve it?